# Screen session is not creating and running on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server

I connected via ssh to my Ubuntu server.
And I want to create a screen session with a command to run sh script.

I'm trying to do it this way:

```
screen -dm -S myserver server/start.sh
```

But nothing happens.
Even screen list is empty.

```
screen -list
No Sockets found in /run/screen/S-root.
```

How can I fix it?

Ubuntu 20.04, Screen version 4.08.00 (GNU) 05-Feb-20

Also, I want to put this command on system unit, to make systemd to run the script at system boot. But I can't to make it runs even using a command via ssh.

Comment: Perhaps also ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that script was failing with an error. I should make cd to run the script.

```
screen -S myserver -dm bash -c "cd server;sh start.sh"
```